# Developing maven plugin - configuration parameters in pom doesn't resolve

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I've created a Maven plugin which works as expected. The only problem is that in the project that I use the new plugin, the configurations doesn't get resolved (in the pom). So the plugin resolves the correct value, but the values in the pom-file are red, and intellij gives this warning:

```
Element employees is not allowed here
```

F.ex. on this configuration:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Janet</url>
        <department>IT</department>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Paul</url>
        <department>IT</filter>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Here is the BusinessMojo where I use the property:

```
@Parameter(property = "business.employees" defaultValue = "")
private List<Employee> employees;
```

When I use the `employees` variable in the plugin, the value is correct. Still, in the pom, the `employees` is red and not resolved.

Comment: Which maven version do you run ?

Comment: maven 3.0.5 currently

Comment: Have you configured pom.xml of your plugin to enable Java5 annotations ? http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html#POM_configuration

Comment: Yes, this dependency is added to my plugin's pom.xml :)

Comment: Does the problem only occurs in intellij-idea, or also when trying to run the plugin through command line ?

Comment: Have you sorounded the configuration with `<configuration><employees>...</employees></configuration>`?

Comment: Yeah, it's surrounded by <configuration>. I feel like I've tried everything without getting any wiser... When I run from the command line I don't get a warning. My worry is that people will think their configuration is wrong, if intellij doesn't resolve it for the plugin (I know I would).

Comment: Found the answer... Restart of IntelliJ did the trick.